# What is the most reliable way to install transitions and molding for laminate flooring on concrete flooring?

Tags: flooring, laminate

Can you please tell me what is the most reliable way to install transition strips and molding for laminate flooring on concrete flooring?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Most of them come with steel channels that you'd fasten with plastic anchors or other concrete fasteners. The moldings press into the channels.

A technique for moldings without channels is to drill 1/2" holes in the concrete, plug them with treated wood dowels, and simply nail down the molding.

Comment: I have read that it is better to fasten the laminate flooring transition strips and molding with an expandable silicone. Is this correct?

Comment: "Expandable"? Silicone is a very poor adhesive in high traffic situations. It's too soft and tears away readily. You could use a construction adhesive, but that's rather permanent.

Answer (score 1):

I used construction adhesive like @isherwood mentioned.  I will pay for it later when the time comes to remove them, but for now, I am quite pleased with how they have held up (10 years).